# Where can I find documentation on the "use" directive in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I am using Chicken Scheme and I am attempting to understand the meaning of `(use abcd)` and how it differs from `(require-extension abcd)`. The Chicken website does not seem to have sufficient information to clarify and a web search provided no helpful information. If Anyone would point Me in the direction of such documentation, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the [documentation](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Non-standard%20macros%20and%20special%20forms#use):

```
use
[syntax] (use ID ...)

use is just a shorter alias for require-extension.
```

And just in case:

```
require-extension
[syntax] (require-extension ID ...)

This is equivalent to (require-library ID ...) but performs an implicit import,
if necessary. Since version 4.4.0, ID may also be an import specification (using
rename, only, except or prefix).

This implementation of require-extension is compliant with SRFI-55 (see the
SRFI-55 document for more information).
```

Comment: Yet again, Óscar, You come to My rescue. Thank You very much!